# how to filter list data in descending order in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, filter, togglebutton

From the Android app, I wrote for I want to add, add a button in the toolbar that acts as a toggle. When the toggle is disabled (the default state) all posts should be shown, when it is enabled (after a tap) the list should only show the posts having user_id set to 1 and sorted by descending published_at. Tapping on the button again will return it to its default state.
Note that publishedAt returning date  and publishedAt and user_id coming from postList from the server I want to know how can I implement above requirement what kind of steps should I have to follow

below my logic implementation in MainActivity.kt

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
@Inject
lateinit var restInterface: RestInterface


private fun initializeDagger() = App.appComponent.inject(this)

var context: Context? = null
private var filteredList: List<Post>? = null



private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
private var switch1: Switch? = null
private var restAdapter: RestAdapter? = null

private var postList: List<Post>? = null
private var restList: RestList? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    initializeDagger()
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
    switch1 = findViewById(R.id.switch1)
    fetchPosts()

    switch1.setOnclickListener {

        postList.forEach { postItem: Post ->
            if (postItem.userId == 1)
                filteredList.add(postItem)
        }

        recyclerView.post = filteredList
        recyclerView.notifyDatasetChanged()

    }
    // Collections.sort( filteredList.get(4).publishedAt, Collections.reverseOrder());
}





private fun fetchPosts() {
    val progress = ProgressDialog(this)
    progress.setMessage("Loading... ")
    progress.isIndeterminate = true
    progress.show()
    restInterface?.getPosts?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(object : DisposableSingleObserver<Response<RestList>>() {
            override fun onSuccess(response: Response<RestList>) {
                restList = response.body()

                val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
                recyclerView?.layoutManager = layoutManager

                // initialize postList with posts
                postList = restList?.posts
                restAdapter = postList?.let { RestAdapter(it, restList) }
                recyclerView?.adapter = restAdapter
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                progress.dismiss()
                Toast.makeText(context, "" + e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })

}
```

}

below my RestAdapter.kt

```
class RestAdapter(val post: List<Post>,val restList: RestList?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RestAdapter.PostHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.post_list, null)
        return PostHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return post.size
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostHolder, position: Int) {
        val posts = post[position]
        Picasso
            .get() // give it the context
            .load(posts.image) // load the image
            .into(holder.postImage)
        holder.userId.text = posts.userId.toString()
        holder.postTitle.text = posts.title
        holder.postTime.text = posts.publishedAt
        holder.postDescription.text = posts.description


    }

    class PostHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val postImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postImage)
        val userId: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userId)
        val postTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postTitle)
        val postTime: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postTime)
        val postDescription: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postDescription)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method .sortedByDescending or .sortedBy on list :)

[Edit] 
I give you a simple solution for that, maybe not the best but should work
1. Change RestAdapter constructor to (var post: List,val restList: RestList?)
Add method to updateData in apadapter:

```
fun filterData(isChecked: Boolean) {
   if (isChecked) {
         val filteredList = arrayListOf<Post>()
         filteredList.addAll(restList?posts.filter { it.user_id  == 1 }.sortedByDescending { it.published_at })
         post = filteredList
     } else {
         post = restList?.posts
     }
    notifyDatasetChanged()
}
```

And in your class use this:

```
 switch1.setOnclickListener {

   restAdapter?.filterData(switch1.isChecked()//state of your switch i.e isChecked() which return true or false)
}
```

Comment: how damien can you tell me step by step with coding sample

Comment: Do you need an example of implementing the whole solution or just sorting the list?

Comment: I need whole solution but first give me any solution it will be helpful let me know what or which classes I have to add to the post

Comment: Your adapter class will be helpful.

Comment: I have added please check it

Comment: check my answare

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206881/discussion-between-sashabeliy-and-damieng).

Comment: if I change constructor to var post: List in RestAdapter I am getting error